# TCP connection not being made after holepunching

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, hole-punching

So I'm trying to implement TCP holepunching between two mobile devices (android mobile and laptop with USB mobile broadband modem). I use another laptop connected to wifi to act as the server.

I first get the laptop to connect to a server which displays its public IP address and the NAT'd port number that the server sees.

```
 try{
        System.out.println("connect to server");

        Socket connectToServer = new Socket();
        System.out.println("49");
        connectToServer.bind(new InetSocketAddress(myIPAddress.getHostAddress(), myPort));
        System.out.println("51");
        connectToServer.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIPAddress.getHostAddress(), serverPort));
        System.out.println("connected to server: " + connectToServer);
        connectToServer.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception 1 :" + e.toString());
        //connectToServer.close();
    }
```

The mobile does the same thing so I see it's public IP and NAT's port number.
The laptop and mobile both close their connections to the server.

The laptop then connects to the mobile using the same local IP and port number (that it used to connect to the server) and using the mobile's public IP and NAT'd port number.

```
    try{
        Socket punchSocket = new Socket();
        System.out.println("33");
        punchSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(myIPAddress.getHostAddress(), myPort));
        System.out.println("35");
        punchSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mobileAddress.getHostAddress(), mobilePort));
        punchSocket.close();


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("exception 2 caught " + e.toString());

    }
```

And since the mobile phone is behind a nat, the connection times out and I get an exception.

```
try{
                Socket mobileSocket = new Socket();
                System.out.println("105");
                mobileSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(myIPAddress.getHostAddress(), myPort));
                System.out.println("124");
                mobileSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mobileAddress.getHostAddress(), mobilePort));
                System.out.println("connection made: " + mobileSocket);
                mobileSocket.close();


            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("exception 2 caught " + e.toString());

            }
```

Finally, I try to connect to the mobile again. While the laptop is attempting to connect to the mobile, I also initiate a connection from the mobile phone. Using the same IP and port (the mobile used to connect to the server), I connect to the laptop's public IP and Port.

but both mobile and laptop attempts to connect just time out.

Instead of just trying to connect from the laptop to the mobile the second time, I have also tried to have the laptop listen for a connection:

```
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(myPort, 50, myIPAddress);

        welcomeSocket.setSoTimeout(5);
        System.out.println("Start listening for mobile to connect");


        while(true){
        try{
            Socket newsock = welcomeSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("connection made: " + newsock);

            }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception 4 caught " + e.toString());

           }
         }
```

But this didn't work either. I have no idea why. Is there a way for me to test if my mobile provider's NAT will even allow holepunching?

This is how I connect from the mobile phone:

```
try {
        Log.d("stop", "line 64");
        InetAddress serverIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
        InetAddress myIPAddress = InetAddress.getByName(myIP); //InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
        Log.d("stop", "line");
        Log.d("localHost: ", myIPAddress.getHostAddress());
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
        Log.d("stop", "line 70");
        clientSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(myIPAddress.getHostAddress(), myPort));
        Log.d("stop", "line 72");
        clientSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverIPAddress.getHostAddress(), serverPort));
        Log.d("stop", "line 74");

        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
        receivedMessage = inFromClient.readLine();
        Log.d("stop", "line 78");


        clientSocket.close();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "socket connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return receivedMessage; //receivedMessage;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        //Toast.makeText(this, "socket caughyt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        error1 = "no Server";
        Log.d("error", error1 + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I have spent most of today trying to figure this out. When serversocket is being used on the laptop, the error on the mobile is a timeout. It randomly worked once last night (1am) and I went to bed. Not working again today. 
No idea why not. 
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Okay so now after the laptop attempts to connect to mobile and fails (and then continuously attempts to connect to the mobile-not the server socket scenario), the mobile attempts to connect to the laptop and gets through. If I delete the lines:
    BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
            receivedMessage = inFromClient.readLine();
then the mobile says it has connected. if I leave the lines in, the mobile receives an error that the peer reset the connection.

However, in either case, the laptop doesn't seem to respond at all. If I use the server socket alternative instead of trying to connect from the laptop, the mobile fails trying to connect as the connection times out.

Comment: Update: took me a while but I realised that the NAT providing my mobile phone and USB modem with IP addresses has several public IP's so both devices were actually behind the same NAT and in the same private network. So tomorrow I'm going to get another operator's SIM and see if hole-punching actually works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a good solution for finding the correct public addresses of the two devices. However, even with this information, many (or maybe even most) mobile networks will still not allow incoming TCP connections to a mobile device.

Some will have different restrictions for different devices types, which may be why you are seeing it sometimes work with the Mobile broadband modem but never with the phone. These differences may even be simply because the Modem and the phone connections are set up differently in the operators networks (use different APN's with different rules for example).

You are most likely aware, but you can still communicate end to end using a server as a 'relay' point in the middle - this obviously adds server side complexity to your solution, but it has the advantage of working reliably across most operators. The approach looks something like:

- Laptop connectes to server
- Mobile connectes to server
- Laptop asks server for list of connected devices and 'discovers' Mobile
- Laptop sends a message for Mobile. It actually sends the messages to the server with an indication that it is to be sent on to the mobile.
- The server notifies the mobile that a message is available for it (using some sort of message notification like Google Cloud Messaging for example, or simply by the devices polling regularly to see if they have any messages).
- The mobile retrieves the messages from the server.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.
so now I can consistently connect from the mobile to the laptop. Every time it will connect on the mobile side. But the laptop side will not recognise this. Is there a way to open a server socket on the same port while trying to connect from it as well? I don't see how the mobile can connect to the natted IP and Port of the laptop if the laptop isn't trying to connect. 

I am using a mobile phone sim in the USB modem. Would using the same APN as on my phone help?